# Entity Framework Many-to-many mixing IDs while inserting to database.

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have something that I am massively confused about. Hope the question is clear enough because I don't know what and how else to say it. Here it goes.

I have a many-to-many table:

```
public partial class ProductsTable
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<HicCodes> HicCodes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DrugsTable> Drugs { get; set; }

        public ProductsTable()
        {
            this.HicCodes = new HashSet<HicCodes>();
            this.Drugs = new HashSet<DrugsTable>();
        }
    }
```

HIC3 Code

```
public class HicCodes
{
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int HicCodeID { get; set; }
        public string HicCode { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductsTable> Products { get; set; }

        public HicCodes()
        {
            this.Products = new HashSet<ProductsTable>();
        }
    }
```

So, as you see above, the idea is that a HIC3 Code may have one or many Product names, and a Product name may have one or many HIC3 codes.

Data: 
The data is in Access MDB which contains about 53 columns. The program that I have written reads each row at a time, and inserts in to the SQL normalized database - altogether there are about 21 tables.

So, apart from other checks it performs in the database, it checks whether HIC3 is present in the database table or not, if it doesn't exist it inserts in the HIC3 table.

Here's how I'm doing this.

```
using (WVDRGS061Context context = new WVDRGS061Context())
    {

    //Insert HIC3 if HIC3 doesn't already exist in the database.
    var HIC3 = CreateHIC3(HCode);

    //Insert Drug if Drug information doesn't already exist in the database.
    //Not relevant for this question
    var Drug = CreateDrug(DTable);

    context.Drugs.Attach(Drug);
    context.HicCodes.Attach(HIC3);


    ProductsTable Product = (ProductsTable)context.Products.Where(w => w.ProductName.Equals(productName)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (Product != null) 
    {
        var h = Product.HicCodes.Where(x => x.HicCode == HIC3.HicCode).FirstOrDefault();

        var d = Product.Drugs.Where(x => x.DrugID == Drug.DrugID).FirstOrDefault();

        if(h == null || object.Equals(h, default(HicCodes)))
        {

        Product.HicCodes.Add(HIC3);

        }

        if (d == null)
        {
        Product.Drugs.Add(Drug);
        }

    }//end if

    else if (Product == null || object.Equals(Product, default(ProductsTable)))
    {

        Product = new ProductsTable();
        Product.ProductName = productName;
        Product.HicCodes.Add(HIC3);
        Product.Drugs.Add(Drug);
        context.Products.Add(Product);
    }//end else if

    try
    {
        context.SaveChanges();

    }//end try
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Fatal(e.Message + " " + e.InnerException);
        ClaimsErrorsList.Add(e.Message);
    }//end catch

    return Product;
    }//end context
```

The Entity framework creates a junction table ProdHiccode table that has Hic3ID and ProductID. So, what seems to be happening is that the EF inserts the data and the ID into these junction table, but the Product ID is being inserted into HIC3ID and HIC3ID being inserted into ProductID in the junction table. I don't seem to understand how this can happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any way to get away from many-to-many relationships across the board?

Comment: I'd love to. Can you perhaps elaborate and give me an example? But nothing I can think of.

Comment: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/

Comment: Turned out I had made a mistake in left and right key in fluent API. That's why it was storing the IDs backwards. It's working properly now.